# Windows 8.1 computer management tree label on Chinese language

Tags: windows-8.1

In the Computer Management window the word in brackets that should say local is in Chinese.
Why is this happening?
[image]

Comment: More information would be nice - What language localisation and version is your copy of windows? Have you run any theme modification packs? Also, I'm wondering what that actually says, the punctuation seems off.

Comment: localisation: English(UK), version 6.3 (build 9600), no theme and modification packs.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. 
Reinstalled language packs and now all ok.
http://goo.gl/yYfqIe